# What real damage did Snape inflict on Voldemort?

Tags: harry-potter

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/154641/why-did-voldemort-kill-lily-potter-instead-of-stunning-her) got me wondering what murder of Lily Potter cost Voldemort. Yes, Snape became a double agent. So what? Snape still did all of Voldemort's bidding. And, as far as I know, Snape never hindered Voldemort's path (even if he was assigned by Dumbledore to protect Hogwarts students, I don't think he would have dared stop the dark lord if ever tried to kill a student).

If Voldemort really had stupefied Lily Potter, how would things be different from Voldemort's perspective? Could dead Voldemort (his soul) have regretted his action of killing Lily Potter, assuming a dead man knows everything?

Comment: Closely related: [What concrete aid did Severus Snape provide the Order while he was under cover?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/154750/what-concrete-aid-did-severus-snape-provide-the-order-while-he-was-under-cover)

Comment: This is not an opinion based question, this question is asking whether there's evidence as to what extent Snape hindered Voldemort and whether had simply stunned her would Snape have been of a much greater use than he was?

Comment: @Edlothiad I beg to differ. `If Voldemort really had stupefied Lily Potter, how would things be different from Voldemort's perspective?` and `Could dead Voldemort (his soul) have regretted his action of killing Lily Potter, assuming a dead man knows everything` is the definition of POB and Opinion-based debate

Comment: @Aegon I see your point, either way, the people decided.

Comment: Without Snape, Harry wouldn't have been master of the Elder Wand, and Voldemort would presumably have won their final battle.  That was kind of unplanned though.

Answer (score 5):

Technically, Snape *did* do Voldemort's bidding, but he typically did it in ways that were subtly (or not-so-subtly) undermining to Voldemort's purposes, such as

> the fact that he planted the idea for Harry Potter's transfer on the Order.

Technically, he gave Voldemort correct information (such as the real date of the event), which was enough to divert suspicion from him, but obviously his information was incomplete to say the least.

He was also able to protect the students at Hogwarts to some degree (e.g. witness the fact that he sent Ginny Weasley to do detention with Hagrid in the Forbidden Forest instead of being subjected to the Cruciatus Curse).

Perhaps the most significant example, of course, was

> the fact that he smuggled the Sword of Gryffindor to Harry Potter so they could destroy the Locket horcrux with it.

Dumbledore also implied in the 5th book that Snape gave him some rather critical information. It's not specified exactly what that was, but

> presumably it included (among other things) the fact that the Potters were being targeted by Voldemort

Also closely related: [What concrete aid did Severus Snape provide the Order while he was under cover?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/154750/what-concrete-aid-did-severus-snape-provide-the-order-while-he-was-under-cover)

It's also worth noting that, due to the fact that the Trio was traveling with a portrait of Phineas Nigellus Black, Snape was able to pass them information and keep tabs on them at the same time. In fact, there were times where he appeared to have known more about Harry Potter's whereabouts and activities than the Order itself.

Comment: How is helping Ginny a damage to Voldemort?

Comment: @ILoveYou That one was probably less directly damaging to Voldemort, but it's still illustration of how Snape typically did Voldemort's bidding in ways that were subtly undermining